# something about inet_ntoa()

Tags: c, linux, unix

I write a server using the function `char* inet_ntoa(struct in_addr in),` When I included the header
`<sys/socket.h>` and `<netinet/in.h>` ,an executable binary can be generated with compiler warnings, but a segment fault happens, when the program handle the return string from `inet_ntoa`. But when I added the header `<arpa/inet.h>,` everything seems ok.

What's the matter?

Comment: Have you debugged it? Ran it through valgrind?

Comment: The [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_ntoa) _tells_ you that you need `<arpa/inet.h>`, always read the manual pages for the function you use if you have trouble with them.

Comment: I also recommend you use [`inet_ntop`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_ntop) instead, as it can handle different protocols (like IPv6) and also is thread safe.

Comment: I guess you haven't checked the compiler warning messages...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`arpa/inet.h` contains the declaration of `char* inet_ntoa(struct in_addr in)`. If you don't include this header your compiler will use implicit declaration `int inet_ntoa()`. Wrong declaration can easily lead to segfault, especially if you are on system where `sizeof(int)!=sizeof(void*)`.

If you are using `gcc` you can add `-Wall` flag. `gcc` will warn you about using functions without explicit declaration.

Comment: what is the implicit declaration "int inet_ntoa()"?

Comment: If you use undeclared function, C compiler will assume it accepts any arguments and returns int. This is called implicit declaration. As opposed to explicit declaration when you properly declare function before using it.

Comment: but,even if the compilation has passed, how can link go on without a function definition？

Comment: You have a definition. It's in your system libraries. Linking will be done even if the declarations don't match.